# Limit of a Partial Sum of a given expression

Tags: limits

I tried solving this problem by getting the partial sum and then letting n, but it didn't work. This problem arose in my limits and continuity chapter while I was studying real analysis. I also tried to break it down into two summations but did not help. Any idea to solve this one?
$$
\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \sum_{k=0}^{n} \frac{k(n-k) !+(k+1)}{(k+1) !(n-k) !}=\cdots
$$

Comment: Yes split the the sum, and use that $e=\sum_{n\ge 0}^{}\frac{1}{n!}$

Answer (score 0):

Given the problem
$$
S = \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \sum_{k=0}^{n} \frac{k(n-k) !+(k+1)}{(k+1) !(n-k) !}
$$
Then split the fraction in two parts
$$
S= \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \sum_{k=0}^{n} [ \frac{k(n-k)!}{(k+1) !(n-k) !} + \frac{k+1}{(k+1) !(n-k) !} ]
$$
Simplify the fraction and split in two summations
$$
S = \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \sum_{k=0}^{n} \frac{k}{(k+1)!} +
\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \sum_{k=0}^{n} \frac{1}{(k) !(n-k) !}
$$
Sustitute $k \rightarrow k + 1$
$$
S = \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{k - 1}{k!} +
\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \sum_{k=0}^{n} \frac{1}{(k) !(n-k) !}
$$
Ignore null term in the left, and some basic manipulations in the right
$$
S = \sum_{k=2}^{\infty} \frac{k - 1}{k!} +
\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \sum_{k=0}^{n} \binom{n}{k} \frac{1}{n!}
$$
$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \sum_{k=0}^{n} \binom{n}{k} \frac{1}{n!}$ evaluates to zero, so we get rid of it
$$
S = \sum_{k=2}^{\infty} \frac{k - 1}{k!}
$$
And this evaluates to
$$
S = 1
$$